# how to send midi controller messages in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-audio, midi

I'm trying to play a MIDI file using Core Audio.
Creating an Audio unit graph and to playing the notes seems to be fine.
However, controller messages (e.g Brightness, Reverb, Attack and Release time) are not being executed.

I've tried to send these commands to both the sampler and the mixer audioUnits, but without any luck:

`MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(mixerUnit, channelEvent.status, channelEvent.data1, channelEvent.data2, 0);`

Anyone?

Comment: Could you please provide more debugging information - any error message?

Comment: Are you sure the instrument you're playing responds to those controller messages? There's nothing that says every instrument has to respond to every controller.

Comment: The problem was that I didn't create the audio graph correctly. I've found out that controllers should have their own audio units (`kAudioUnitType_Effect`).